# How to fix GTMetrix showing Minify JavaScript option for external url in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, infusionsoft

Gtmetrix shows F(0) for Minify Javascript for appointmentcore and infusionsoft.

Ex: 
https://www.appointmentcore.com/frontend/js/lib/jquery/plugins/availChooser/jquery.availChooser-2.0.3.js could save 47.5KiB (54% reduction).

https://www.appointmentcore.com/frontend/js/lib/rrule-metcalf/lib/rrule.js could save 38.1KiB (58% reduction).

https://www.appointmentcore.com/frontend/js/app-v1529684716.js could save 37.2KiB (56% reduction).

https://www.appointmentcore.com/frontend/js/app/utils-v1463861748.js could save 13.6KiB (53% reduction).

https://www.appointmentcore.com/frontend/js/lib/jquery/plugins/datepicker/jquery.datepick.js could save 8.4KiB (42% reduction) after compression.

http://wordpress-135827-551615.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/themes/DiviChild/js/owl.carousel.js could save 6.2KiB (35% reduction) after compression.

Is there any solution for it?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is old.  There are two ways you can fix this.

First: Edit the file from the external connection to be minified and keep the connection.

Second: Copy the file into your internal, minify it, create a function for the the plugin or theme to link to that file instead of the external connection.  You can create a cron job that will download the external file, then minify it, and overwrite your current minified file at least once a day.

EDIT: If you have no way of minifying the file then you are out of luck.

According to the comment: You cannot edit an iframe content unless you also have access to edit the iframe content.

Comment: I have added iframe from the third-party domain. So this is not possible.